# want jquery accordion centered but always aligning right

Tags: jquery

Happy Holidays,

I'm trying to use jquery ui accordion for my site that I am creating.  I want the accordion to be centered vertically and horizontally in the center of the page.  I've searched stackoverflow for the answer to the question but nothing seems to make the accordion center, it always is at the far right hand side of the screen.  How can I change the CSS of the overcast theme to make the accordion centered?  I've used the below code structure for the accordion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function centerIt(){
    var $accordion = $('.accordion');
    $accordion.css('top', ($(window).height() - $accordion.height())/2);
}
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Resume</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/ResumePage.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- Google Code for Resume webite Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]>=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-77421138-3', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()  {
           $("#accordion").accordion();
});
</script>
<div class="container" align="center">
<div class="navigation">
<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="About_Me_Page1.html" title="About Me">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="Resume_page.html" title="Resume Page">Resume</a></li>
<li><a href="References_page.html" title="Reference Page">References</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<table align="center" cols="1" width="50%">
<div id="accordion" align="center">
<div class="contact" align="center">
<p class="contact">
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox layout to do what you want to do

```
<style>
    #accordion-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
</style>
<div id="accordion-container">
   <div id="accordion"> ... </div>
</div>
```

[This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a very helpful guide that you can use.